# How to save dynamically edited layout to storage

Tags: android

I am creating Card maker App.That will create card and save as bitmap.I succsessfully created bitmap of card but my problem is i want to reEdit created card.I dont know how to save full layout view in storage or database and how to fetch old layout when user reEdit the card.

I want to save Full Layout in Storage.After saving specific layout i can able to edit this layout.Following is my piece of code.

```
private List<View> addedViews=new ArrayList<>();;

final View imageRootView = 
mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_photo_editor_text, null);
final ImageView imageView = 
imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorImage);
final FrameLayout frmBorder = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.frmBorder);
final ImageView imgClose = 
imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorClose);
final ImageView imgPhotoEditorPush = 
imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorPush);

addedViews.add(rootView);
```

So i have List of multiple Views.How can i save this List of Views.

Comment: I really don't get it, why you need to save the layout state as bitmap a re-edit it later. You should better to store the data in `SharedPreferences`/Cloud/SQLite and then just restore them into layout.

Comment: please paste code how can i Create it.

Comment: how can restore singe view exact that place where it is make first time?